# Type an incoming function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How would I Type this incoming function prop for this React Hook Componet?  Right now I just put `any` which is bad but I don't know how to type it, I'm new to TS:

```
const FeaturedCompanies = (findFeaturedCompanies: any) => {
...
}
```

It's just a plain function:

```
async function findFeaturedCompanies(): Promise<Array<Company>> {
  const response = await fetchFeaturedCompanies(),
    ...
}
```

Comment: Depends on what `findFeaturedCompanies` resolves to - need to see the `...`

Comment: ok let me update it to specify more about what it resolves to.  Good point, that function should have been typed as well but this was old code and I hadn't converted it to TS yet

Comment: I just wonder whats the point to pass an async function as a prop instead of what that function resolves to. Consider changing your logic slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `findFeaturedCompanies` returns `Promise<Array<Company>>`, just type the function as one which returns that:

```
const FeaturedCompanies = (
  findFeaturedCompanies: () => Promise<Array<Company>>
) => {
```

If `findFeaturedCompanies` happens to be in scope of the `FeaturedCompanies` declaration, you could also do

```
const FeaturedCompanies = (
  findFeaturedCompanies: typeof findFeaturedCompanies
) => {
```

Comment: what if the React function's props though are surrounded with {} like `const FeaturedCrafters = ({findFeaturedCompanies: () => Promise<Array<Company>>})` - that doesn't wokr

Comment: It's a property of an object, so you have to define the type of the object: `const FeaturedCrafters = ({ findFeaturedCompanies }: { findFeaturedCompanies: () => Promise<Array<Company>> }) => {`

Comment: hmm ok usually with React components you just need to specify property and TS type wrapped in {} only